# MVC Razor Shared Layout Page Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I have an MVC 5 App which uses Razor and a Shared_Layout File.  They Layout file works fine and includes my menu's.

The problem I have is when I try to use it in combination with a page used dhtmlxgannt jquery scripts.  When I comment out the shared Layout, the page renders as I expect but I get no menu's at the top of my page.  When I leave the shared layout in the file, my page does not render the gannt chart is seems to shrink into a small container and all i can see is a horizontal scroll bar.

**Shared Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mojito</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Mojito", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

                    </ul>
                    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers", new { area = "Customers" }, null)</li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Projects<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Index", "ProjectTasks", new { area = "Project" }, null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Gannt Chart", "Gannt", "ProjectTasks", new { area = "Project" }, null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Gannt Chart", "Index", "GanttTasks", new { area = "Project" }, null)</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Kronos<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Pay Codes", "Index", "KronosPayCodes", new { area = "Kronos" }, null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Import From Excel", "Index", "KronosImportData", new { area = "Kronos" }, null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Import From Xml", "Index", "KronosXmlConfiguration", new { area = "Kronos" }, null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Design Document", "Index", "KronosDesignDocument", new { area = "Kronos" }, null)</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mojito</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

**Gannt Chart View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
@model IEnumerable<Mojito.Domain.Entities.GanttTask>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/dhtmlxgantt/dhtmlxgantt.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/dhtmlxgantt/dhtmlxgantt.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Dhtmlxgannt/CodeBase/testdata.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 40px;
            overflow: hidden}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="ganntcontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <script type="text/javascript">

    dhtmlx.message("Try to move or resize task to not working time");

    gantt.config.work_time = true;
    gantt.config.correct_work_time = true;

    gantt.config.scale_unit = "day";
    gantt.config.date_scale = "%D, %d";
    gantt.config.min_column_width = 60;
    gantt.config.duration_unit = "day";
    gantt.config.scale_height = 20 * 3;
    gantt.config.row_height = 30;



    var weekScaleTemplate = function (date) {
        var dateToStr = gantt.date.date_to_str("%d %M");
        var weekNum = gantt.date.date_to_str("(week %W)");
        var endDate = gantt.date.add(gantt.date.add(date, 1, "week"), -1, "day");
        return dateToStr(date) + " - " + dateToStr(endDate) + " " + weekNum(date);
    };

    gantt.config.subscales = [
        { unit: "month", step: 1, date: "%F, %Y" },
        { unit: "week", step: 1, template: weekScaleTemplate }

    ];

    gantt.templates.task_cell_class = function (task, date) {
        if (!gantt.isWorkTime(date))
            return "week_end";
        return "";
    };

    gantt.init("ganntcontainer");
    gantt.parse(demo_tasks);
        </script>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes but I dont really want to have the scripts for gannt running on my layout page as that is used for every page in the app, whereas the scripts on the gannt chart page are specific to that page.  I also just tried that to see if it would render correctly and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using Layouts is avoid duplicated code, 
On you gant chart view you only need the body section,

EG:

```
<div id="ganntcontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
@section scripts {
//Your scripts here
}
```